# To find the p values in hypothesis testing

Tags: statistics, hypothesis-testing

The null hypothesis says that at least 20% of college students are left-handed. If we took a sample of 20 college students and let $X$ be the number of lefties in the sample. Calculate the p values if

$X=1$

$X=2$

Hint: If the null hypothesis is true, $X$ follows binomial distribution.

My attempt-

I tried applying the binomial formula for $X=1$
$${20 \choose 1} 0.5^{20}$$ and this is approx. 0.0001 and for $X=2$ $${20 \choose 2} 0.5^{20} + {20 \choose 1} 0.5^{20}$$ but getting my answer wrong.

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site! Since this is a site that encourages and helps with *learning*, it is best if you show your own ideas and efforts in solving the question. Can you edit your question to add your thoughts and ideas about it? Don't worry if it's wrong - that's what we're here for.

Comment: Also, don't get discouraged by the downvote. I downvoted the question and voted to close it because at the moment, it is not up to site standards (you have shown no work you did on your own). If you edit your question so that you show what you tried and how far you got, I will not only remove the downvote, I will add an upvote.

Comment: Hint: look at the formula for a one sample test for proportions.

Comment: @5xum edited as said by you

Answer (score 1):

With the null hypothesis being true, the binomial distribution will be B(0.2,20) since p=20%.
The problem is a one-sided alternative problem, hence when
X<= X_Critical_Value : We Accept the alternative
X> X_Critical_Value : We retain the Null Hypothesis

1. for $ X=1 $
   the $P=P(x<=1)=P(X=0)+P(X=1)=0.0115+0.0576=0.06912$
2. for $ X=2 $
   the $P=P(x<=2)=P(X=0)+P(X=1)+P(X=2)=0.0115+0.0576+0.1369=0.206$

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).